# Integer not updating

Tags: c++, k-means

Hi I can’t seem to work out why my program crashes in visual studio when running it. When debugging it I get the error “integer division by 0”. I have commented the line in the code where the error is taking place. The aim of this program is to demonstrate a basic k-means clustering algorithm.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int m1, o1;
int mem1[10];
int sum1;
int in1; 

int m2, o2;
int mem2[10];
int sum2;
int in2;


int arr[10] {21, 135, 45, 174, 10, 64, 85, 44, 96, 125};

int random_mean()
{
    m1 = rand() % 255;
    m2 = rand() % 255;

    return 0;
}

int clustering(int x)
{

    int d1;
    int d2;


    d1 = sqrt((pow(m1 - x, 2)));
    d2 = sqrt((pow(m2 - x, 2)));

    if (d1 < d2)
    {
        mem1[in1] = x;
        in1++;
    }
    else if (d2 < d1)
    {
        mem2[in2] = x;
        in2++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int updatemean()
{
    o1 = m1;
    o2 = m2;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < in1; i++)
    {
        sum1 += mem1[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < in2; i++)
    {
        sum2 += mem2[i];
    }

    m1 = sum1 / in1; //error is taking place on this line
    m2 = sum2 / in2;

    in1 = 0;
    in2 = 0;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    random_mean();

    do
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            clustering(arr[i]);
        }
        updatemean();
    } while (o1 != m1 && o2 !=m2);

    return 0;
}
```

1. The program starts by randomly assigning values to (m1) and (m2) which act as cluster means. The program then calls the (clustering) function 10 times, on each call a value from the array (arr) is passed to the function.
2. In the clustering function, the distance between the passed value and each mean is calculated. The value is then added to either (mem1) or (mem2) depending on which had the shortest distance. Once added, either (in1) or (in2) is incremented.
3. After all 10 values have been passed and added to their respective arrays, the program then calls the (updatemean) function and this is where the problem is occurring. The function copies the values from (m1) and (m2) to the variables (o1) and (o2). The sum of (mem1) and (mem2) is then calculated and saved. (m1) and (m2) are then updated. Each one is updated with the sum of the array (mem1) or (mem2) divided by the number of elements in the array (in1) or (in2). For example m1 = sum1 / in1. The variables (in1) and (in2) are then reset.
4. The program repeats steps 2 and 3 until the do/while loop’s condition is met. I can’t seem to work out why on the second do/while loop the (updatemean) function is giving an error when the (clustering) function before it has incremented the (in1) and (in2) all over again.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: U need to initialize you variables.

Comment: Well, an excellent case, to start learning how to use your toolchains debugger.

Comment: Recommend reducing your reliance on global variables. Read up on pass by reference, and functions don't always have to return int.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case when for every d1 and d2, the statement: d1 < d2 is true, then value of in2 will never be incremented. Likewise, if the statement d1 < d2, is always false, the value of in1 will never be incremented, and their values will remain 0, leading to the divison by zero in line:

```
m1 = sum1 / in1;
```

You can solve this problem by setting a simple if, that checks whether in1 is actually zero:

```
if( in1 == 1) m1 = 0; else m1 = sum1 / in1;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Using this method does allow the program to run, but in1 and in2 should never be 0 though.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation of the means is erroneous because you're using global variables for sum1 and sum2 and never reset these global variables to zero.

Thus your computations keep accumulating new values on top of the previous averages, and sum1 and sum2 diverge toward infinity. After a few iterations, all points fall into one cluster, and the number of points for the other cluster reaches down to zero, hence the divison-by-zero error you get at that stage.

Simply define sum1 and sum2 as local (initialized) variables, and it will be ok:

```
int updatemean()
{
    o1 = m1;
    o2 = m2;

    int sum1 = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < in1; i++)
        sum1 += mem1[i];
    m1 = sum1 / in1;
    in1 = 0;

    int sum2 = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < in2; i++)
        sum2 += mem2[i];
    m2 = sum2 / in2;
    in2 = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

I have only corrected your division-by-zero error though. As advised by others, and as demonstrated by this bug, using more local variables and fewer global variables is advisable in any case.

BTW, I don't know the algorithm itself but I'm surprised to realize you're doing an integer division? Although the input data are integer, shouldn't the sums and the centroids be double-precision floats?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I’m still new to this algorithm and you are right I should be using more accurate data types for this sort of thing.

Comment: Ok, then there are several improvements you should make:

Comment: (1) Change your means and sum variables into doubles. (2) Replace sqrt(pow(m-x,2)) with fabs(m-x), which computes the Euclidian distance more efficiently and is far more readable. Then your means will be accurate. without that, your means would be integer-truncated: for example the mean of {0,3} would be truncated to (0+3)/2 = 1 instead of the proper mean (0.+3.)/2 = 1.5

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the error occurs in `updatemean()` because either `in1` or `in2` is still 0. Immediately I see two cases that could cause this.

**Case 1**: If during every call to `clustering(int x)`, `d1` or `d2` was consistently larger than the other, then either `in1` or `in2` may have never been incremented past 0.

**Case 2**: If `d1==d2` during every run, then no action is taken and neither `in1` nor `in2` are incremented past 0.

I believe case 2 is more likely. In your original code, you were saying: `int d1 = sqrt((pow(m1 - x, 2)));` and `int d2 = sqrt((pow(m2 - x, 2)));`. The issue here is that `sqrt()` returns a double and you were assigning it to an integer. As such, there is a possibility that you values were being rounded off and thus `d1` was the same as `d2`. That said, when reviewing this line I had some questions.

Why on earth are you saying `sqrt(pow(m#-x, 2));` In this statement, you are essentially saying *"Square it and then take the square root."* Mathematically, this statement should always return the value of `m#-x`. *Logic: `sqrt(10^2) = sqrt(100) = 10`.*

Also, in your original code, you said `int arr[10] {21, 135, 45, 174, 10, 64, 85, 44, 96, 125};`. You are missing an equal sign (`=`) between `int arr[10]` and `{21, 135, 45, 174, 10, 64, 85, 44, 96, 125};`.

The following is a modified version of your code. I have added comments, changed some variable types, revised a couple lines, and I included some debug statements that print out the values of variables throughout the code (when `_DEBUG_ == 1`). Hopefully this can help you with revising, improving, and further developing your code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

/* just used a preprocessor way to check if debug statements should be compiled */
#define _DEBUG_     1 // 1=debug mode; 0=non-debug mode

using namespace std;

int m1, o1;
int mem1[10] = {0};
int sum1;
int in1; 

int m2, o2;
int mem2[10] = {0};
int sum2;
int in2;

// Added an equal sign between "arr[10]" and "{21, 135, ...}"
// Previously you had:
// int arr[10] {21, 135, 45, 174, 10, 64, 85, 44, 96, 125};
int arr[10] = {21, 135, 45, 174, 10, 64, 85, 44, 96, 125};

void random_mean()
{
    m1 = rand() % 255;
    m2 = rand() % 255;
}

void clustering(int x)
{
    // Changed from int to double because sqrt() returns a double:
    double d1;
    double d2;

    // What is this? You square it just to square root it?
    d1 = sqrt((pow(m1 - x, 2)));
    d2 = sqrt((pow(m2 - x, 2)));

    if (d1 < d2)
    {
        mem1[in1] = x;
        in1++;
    }
    else if (d1 > d2)
    {
        mem2[in2] = x;
        in2++;
    } // Perhaps you should add a condition in case d1 == d2 (although it is unlikely to occur)

    #if _DEBUG_ == 1
        // Show what the in1 and in2 values are:
        std::cout << "Debug: At the end of clustering() function.\nin1=" << in1 << "; in2=" << in2 << std::endl;
    #endif
}

void updatemean()
{
    o1 = m1;
    o2 = m2;

    for (int i = 0; i < in1; i++)
    {
        sum1 += mem1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < in2; i++)
    {
        sum2 += mem2[i];
    }

    #if _DEBUG_ == 1
        // if _DEBUG_ == 1, then the statements within this preprocessor block
        // will be compiled. Here we will include print statements to show us
        // some of the variable values:
        std::cout << "Debug: In updatemean() before division.\nin1=" << in1 << "; in2=" << in2 << std::endl;
    #endif

    m1 = sum1 / in1; //error is taking place on this line
    m2 = sum2 / in2;

    in1 = 0;
    in2 = 0;
}

int main()
{
    random_mean();

    // Get the size of the array for the for-loop below:
    // (This allows you to adjust the size of the arr above without having to manually
    //  change the for loop below.)
    int iArrayLen = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iArrayLen; i++)
        {
            #if _DEBUG_ == 1
                // Show which iteration count we are at:
                std::cout << "Debug: in1=" << in1 << "; in2=" << in2 << std::endl;
            #endif
            clustering(arr[i]);
        }
        #if _DEBUG_ == 1
            // Show which in1 and in2 values
            std::cout << "Debug: In do-while loop. Outside for loop.\nin1=" << in1 << "; in2=" << in2 << std::endl;
        #endif
        updatemean();
    } while (o1 != m1 && o2 !=m2);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I changed all of your functions that were just returning 0 to now return void (except main, of course). It's pointless to declare a function as returning an *int* when it is just returning 0 every time rather than some useful value.

Comment: I thought about that myself and I don’t know why it is expressed like that. The reason why I used sqrt(pow(m#-x, 2)) was because for calculating the distance in Euclidean space we use:
d=√(x_2 - x_1 )

And when we have more than one input it becomes:
d=√((x_2 - x_1 )^2 + (y_2 - y_1 )^2 )

Comment: Also thanks for the advice, I will begin working on it now.

Comment: @user3178205, the discriminant when calculating Euclidian distance is `(DeltaX)^2 + (DeltaY)^2`. You cannot split these up and square root them separately. You must add them together and then square root. This comes from the fact that `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` Thus `c = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)`.